# Why JavaScript base-36 conversion appears to be ambiguous

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, radix, base36

I am currently writing a piece of JavaScript that uses base 36 encoding.

I came across this problem:

```
parseInt("welcomeback",36).toString(36)
```

Appears to return `"welcomebacg"`.

I tested this in the Chrome developer's console and Node.js with the same result.

Is there any logical explanation for this result?

Comment: My first-thought is that it’s because the parsed value exceeds the maximum possible value that `number` can accurately represent (2^53, but your value is in the order of 36^11) Try using the newer `BigInt` type instead of `number`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `parseInt("welcomeback",36)` is larger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (2<sup>53</sup>-1) and thus cannot be accurately represented. A possible workaround is to perform base conversion with [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) manually.

```js
const str = "welcomeback";
const base = 36;
const res = [...str].reduce((acc,curr)=>
   BigInt(parseInt(curr, base)) + BigInt(base) * acc, 0n);
console.log(res.toString());
console.log(res.toString(36));
```

Answer (score 2):

The number data type in JavaScript is a 64-bit floating point number, and it can safely represent integers only up to 2^53-1, see [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

The result of `parseInt("welcomeback",36)` is above that limit. The result is going to be the closest number that *can* be represented.

A JS Number can safely hold 10 base-36 digits, so an efficient way to parse it into a BigInt is to split the string into chunks of 10 digits, and combine them. The other answers shows a similar technique using `reduce`, here's one using `forEach`:

```
function toBigInt36(str) {
    const multiplier = BigInt(Math.pow(36, 10));
    const chunks = str.match(/.{1,10}/g);
    let result = BigInt(0);
    chunks.forEach((chunk) => {
        result = result * multiplier + BigInt(parseInt(chunk, 36))
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How could I get around this?

Comment: @nph rule of thumb: whenever you find the numbers too big, work with the digits separately.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the [multiformats](https://github.com/multiformats/js-multiformats) package:

```
npm install multiformats
```

And:

```
import { base36 } from "multiformats/bases/base36"

// you have to prepend your base36 string with "k":
const decoded = base36.decode("k" + "welcomebacklongtimenotseen")
console.log(decoded)

// don't forget to remove the leading "k":
const reEncoded = base36.encode(decoded).slice(1)
console.log(reEncoded)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Uint8Array(17) [
   76, 249,  40, 198, 158, 140,
  198,  47,  99, 101, 143,  20,
   54,  15, 186, 196, 239
]
welcomebacklongtimenotseen
```